# How do you wrap a method inside a Class Constructor in JS

Tags: javascript, class, methods, constructor

I have a Class constructor and I'd like to wrap one of the methods with a function. What is the syntax to do so?

```js
// function that wraps around the method
const wrapCatch = (fn) => async (...args) =>
  fn(args).catch(err => throw new Error(err));

class myClass {
  constructor(fn1) {
    this.fn1 = fn1;
  }

  async fnToBeWrapped () {
    return await this.fn1();
  }
}
```

essentially trying to do this but for a class method...

```js
const fnToBeWrapped = wrapCatch(async () => {
  // ...
});
```

Comment: FYI `fn(args)` should probably be `fn(...args)`

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to wrap a method inside a class in Java